# how to do a t test with stratification

Tags: anova, t-test

Suppose I have data in the following format:

```
        [measurement] [group] [stratifier]
  [1,] 0.0212104280    1    2
  [2,] 0.0182411600    1    4
  [3,] 0.0078987265    1    5
  [4,] 0.0247759110    1    6
  [5,] 0.0728231000    1    7
 ....
  [900,] 0.0212104280    2    2
  [901,] 0.0182411600    2    4
  [902,] 0.0078987265    2    5
  [903,] 0.0247759110    2    6
  [904,] 0.0728231000    2    7
 ....
```

There are multiple rows with stratifier value 2, 3, 4,...

Is there a way to do a t-test per stratifier and combine to get if group 1 and 2 have different measurements? Essentially I'm looking for a CMH test (which works on counts) but for continuous data. Ideally I want to see if Groups 1 and 2 are different in their measurement accounting for all the stratifiers. Is Anova enough or just fit a line of:

`lm(measurement=group + stratifier)`?

Comment: You could run a permutation t test blocked by the stratum. In R, this can be done by the awesome `coin` package. Your regression approach might be an option, but it is not really a stratification.

Comment: Duplicate question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346043/is-there-a-way-to-block-a-t-test-in-r

Comment: It would also be important, to understand what this stratifier is?  Can you describe it in terms of your real-world data?

Comment: It's a categorical stratifier. Think car type or disease type.